# Warning: ldap_add(): Add: Object class violation

Tags: php, ldap, phpldapadmin

Over the past few days I've been trying to learn more about ldap, and I would now like to be able to create a new account on my phpldapadmin server from a webform. I have the values being passed back through php correctly, but I keep getting an `objectclass violation` error. I've scoured many different resources ([including this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5728540/ldap-add-add-object-class-violation-error)) and basically all that I can find is that the `objectclass` needs to match exactly how the dictionary is setup. I ran an export for some of the manually created users I already have working in there successfully, and this is an example of the output:

```
# LDIF Export for cn=api user,cn=students,ou=users,dc=myhost,dc=com
# Server: LDAP (ip)
# Search Scope: sub
# Search Filter: (objectClass=*)
# Total Entries: 1
#
# Generated by phpLDAPadmin (http://phpldapadmin.sourceforge.net) on June 4,     2016 3:15 pm
# Version: 1.2.2

version: 1

# Entry 1: cn=api user,cn=students,ou=users,dc=myhost,dc=co...
dn: cn=test user,cn=students,ou=users,dc=myhost,dc=com
cn: test
gidnumber: 502
givenname: test
homedirectory: /home/users/testuser
loginshell: /bin/sh
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
objectclass: posixAccount
objectclass: top
sn: tuser
uid: testuser
uidnumber: 1003
userpassword: {MD5}pass==
```

and I have tried mimicking it as closely as possible in my script (below), but I am still getting the violation error. No problems connecting or with any of the other fields, only the `objectclass` problem.

```
  $ds = ldap_connect($AD_server);  
    if ($ds) {

        ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3); 
        $r = ldap_bind($ds, $AD_Auth_User, $AD_Auth_PWD); 
        $info["cn"] = $user_full_name;
        $info["sn"] = $user_username;
        $info['objectclass'][0] = "top";
        $info['objectclass'][1] = "posixAccount";
        $info['objectclass'][2] = "inetOrgPerson";
        $info['uid'] = $user_username;
        $info['userpassword'] = $newPassw;
        $info['loginshell'] = '/bin/sh';
        $info['homedirectory'] = "/home/users/$user_username";

        // add data to directory
        $r = ldap_add($ds, $dn, $info);

        ldap_close($ds);
    } else {
        echo "Unable to connect to LDAP server";
    }
```

I've played around with the objectclasses and tried switching their positions or using only `inetOrgPerson`, and still no luck. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need to make sure to pass **every value** back through. I was missing the `uidnumber` `givenname` and `gidnumber` fields. But now it works! :)

Answer (score 2):

When creating entries within LDAP you need to know which Attributes are "MUST" (required) for the ObjectClasses used when creating the entry.

In your example:
person MUST ( sn $ cn ) 
posixAccount MUST ( cn $ uid $ uidNumber $ gidNumber $ homeDirectory )

So to create the entry in LDAP you MUST have values for all of these:

- sn
- cn
- uid
- uidNumber
- gidNumber
- homeDirectory

You can tell which is required by a [LDAP Query For Schema](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/LDAP%20Query%20For%20Schema) and reading each ObjectClass to determine which Attributes are "MUST" (required).